# remove function doesnt work until I add if statement with true and false

Tags: c, function

I am working on a project for school, a student management system, and two of the functions are delete a student and modify student info: in both I create a temporary file to store the new updated version, and then I remove the original file and rename the temporary one as the old one, but the `remove` function doesn't work until I assign a bool variable like this `rt = remove("studentDB.txt");` then add an `if` statement that prints successfully modified/deleted if it is true and not deleted /modified if false and it only works if I add this statement and I am confused. Why does this happen?

```
void deletestudent(FILE *fp) {

    system("cls");
    fp = fopen("studentDB.txt", "r");
    FILE *ft = fopen("database.tmp", "w");
    bool rt;
    int line, count;
    char buffer[100];
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\t\t\t 2. Delete a Student \n");
    printf("\t\t---------------------------------------------------------\t\t\t\t\t\t");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\t\t\t ");
    printf("select student id \n");
    printf("\t\t\t ");
    scanf("%d", &line);
    count = 0;
    while ((fgets(buffer, 1000, fp)) != NULL)
    {
        count++;// so that the counting start at 1

        /* If current line is line to replace */
        if (count == line) {
            fputs("", ft);
        } else
            fputs(buffer, ft);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(ft);
    rt = remove("studentDB.txt");
    rename("database.tmp", "studentDB.txt");
    if (rt == TRUE)
        printf("not successfull");
    printf("\t\t\t\t");
    printf("deleted successfully  \n");
    system("pause");
}
```

I am really confused why it works

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. With emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: Please show the code that *doesn't* work.

Comment: And please take some time to read more about  [`remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/remove) and what it really returns. It's not guaranteed to return a specific non-zero value (which `TRUE` is) on failure.

Comment: Consistent indentation makes your code readable.  Writing code that's not readable makes it impossible to understand what's going on...

Comment: One thing that I see is that buffer is initialized to be of size 100 but you read 1000.

Comment: @melodic_n, `fgets(buffer, 1000, fp)` better as `fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp)`

Comment: @melodic_n 1) fix `fgets()`, 2) show how `deletestudent()` is called.  3) Better to add error checking on `fopen()`,  and all I/O related fucntions 4) Better to change renaming sequence.  The point being to not remove  anything until the new file is fully made and has the target name..  Keep in mind you do not want to lose anything if the process fails midway.

Comment: You ask "i am really confused why it works", but it seems to me that you're asking why your old code didn't work. That's the code you should be posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the copying loop, you read lines with `fgets(buffer, 1000, fp)` into an array `buffer` defined with a length of `100`.  If any of the lines in the input file have more than 99 bytes, you have undefined behavior, which could cause different observations depending on you adding extra code.

Use a less error prone approach:

```
    while ((fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp)) != NULL)
```

Note also these remarks:

- it is very important to check for `fopen` failures and report them with an informative message.
- `fputs("", ft);` is useless and has no effect.
- on POSIX compliant systems, the `remove` call is unnecessary as the `rename("database.tmp", "studentDB.txt")` call will remove the destination file and perform the rename in a way that guarantees a file with the name **studentDB.txt** always exists and is atomically replaced with the new file.  You seem to be using the Microsoft Windows system which might behave differently.

In all cases, it is good practice to test and report failure to rename the new file and make sure the old file is still present in case of failure.

Comment: when i removed the remove() the temporary file didnt change names

Comment: @melodic_n: you are probably running your test on Microsoft Windows, which does not support this behavior.

Comment: it drove me insane but i guess thats whats happening i tried evrything